# Why doesn't this javascript code work?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

http://jsfiddle.net/FZQuM/2/

I want the div 'divi' to show what is in the input box 'hitbox'.

**EDIT**: it's really not difficult to place this code here, especially if it's this short

```
document.getElementById('hitbox')
    .onchange(document.getElementById('divi')
               .innerHTML = document.getElementById('hitbox').value;
```

Comment: Why, oh why, do you find it so difficult to put your code _here_ instead of jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onchange` will fire only after the textbox lose focus - to see it "live" use something like `onkeyup` event:

```
document.getElementById('hitbox').onkeyup = function() {
    document.getElementById('divi').innerHTML =this.value;
};
```

(You can also use `this` while in the event handler)

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/FZQuM/10/

Answer (score 6):

The native `onchange` event doesn't work like its jQuery counterpart.

Use

```
document.getElementById('hitbox').onchange = function() { ..... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use .value instead of .text

And i made it an anonymous function:

```
document.getElementById('hitbox').onchange = function () {document.getElementById('divi').innerHTML = this.value};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "value" property instead of text. And use onchange event as property and not as onchange()

http://jsfiddle.net/FZQuM/3